# How i can get the class of a model in a widget through ModelForms in Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i need make a special widget for ForeignKeys in Admin, but i need get the class of model in the widget, somebody know how i can do it?

I think the Widget have a Field, and Field have a ModelForm, and obviously ModelForm have a Model, but i need this model in a widget in the admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps looking at the ModelChoiceField form widget would help? http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/models.py#L921